# Using node.js modules in electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, capacitor

I have the following use case:
I want to develop a desktop application, which will run on a Raspberry Pi. I decided to use Electron to build the desktop application and Angular as the frontend framework (1). 

I need to use some npm modules for my application in order to communicate with the GPIO-pins or over ethernet tcp communication ('net' node module). I tried to import these in my Angular application (for example import {Socket} from 'net';), but I don't get them working.
I get the following error when trying to construct the net socket like this:
`let client = new Socket();`

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new net.Socket()')

Is this an error in the base architecture, that I can't run code, which depends on the backend, in the angular frontend. Or am I doing something else wrong?

I also found capacitor (2), which allows to call native sdks. I tried to implement my own plugin, but I get the same error as above.

Thanks for your help.

(1) https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/

(2) https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have a little confusion about *Electron*, even thou it is not the classical `client:server` model, ...

#### Lets understand Electron first:

---

### Main and Renderer Processes

> The **main** process is for handling/creating BrowserWindows(Renderer) And
>   for some communication from one renderer-Window to an other one.
>   (maybe some other special stuff too)
>
> The **renderer** is where you really run the most of your app. With node,
>   you have all you need there.

you then notice you will be needing a channel between the **renderer process (web page) and the main process.**

Don't worry, here is where [`remote`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) comes in handy :

> ```
> Use main process modules from the renderer process.
> ```
>
> The remote module provides a simple way to do **inter-process communication** (IPC) between the renderer process (web page) and the main process.

...even the other way round...

> Note: For the reverse (access the renderer process from the main
>   process), you can use [webContents.executeJavascript](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback).

So at the end you will be able of using all the magick in both sides.